# What Activesync features are / are not supported when used with Exchange 2013 / 2010

Tags: email, security, exchange

When I connect my Windows Phone to Exchange, are all of the Activesync security features active and readily available?

For most of the earlier Windows Phones, several Activesync security features such as `Local Device encryption` didn't work.

What Exchange 2010 or 2013 features work (or don't work) with Windows Mobile Phones?  (Please note if there are any per carrier or per-vendor differences in support)

Answer (score 1):

Here's an exchange activesync features comparison table which should help you.  http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/1150.exchange-activesync-client-comparison-table.aspx

Comment: That doesn't appear to have any info for Windows Phone 8, only WM6/6.5 and WP7.